# Are one-to-one levels structurally identifiable in a multilevel model?

Tags: mixed-model, identifiability

I have three categorical variables $A$, $B$, and $C$ representing three different levels of spatial regions. Every element of the image of $C$ is a proper subregion of $B$, and likewise for $B$ in relation to $A$. Think like cities nested within provinces and provinces nested within countries as an example; sort of a "natural hierarchy" to the data.

I was thinking of using these categories in a multilevel model where the levels are ordered by the given order on the categorical variables.

But in my data matrix I have noticed that there is a bijection between the $B$ column and the $C$ column. My intuition suggests that there is not any additional information provided to the model if I include both, and I think I should drop either $B$ or $C$ from the analysis. For aesthetic reasons I could prefer to drop $C$, but I could choose based on other reasons (esp. what the target audience of the results would prefer).

- Does the bijection between the sampled values of $B$ and $C$ imply a multilevel model using both $B$ and $C$ would not be structurally identifiable?

Comment: BTW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643386/easy-way-to-see-if-two-columns-are-one-to-one-in-pandas) are some examples of how to check if two columns in a pandas dataframe are one-to-one.

Comment: This one-to-one aspect of the two columns implies that the one-hot-encoded variables would be perfectly multicollinear.